# code is working manually, timer based trigger give no results and shows "Error reporting sheet to PDF!" and "Response code 400". help me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, urlfetch

What's the debug if this code works good manually but not with trigger. Response code 400

```
function exportRangeToPDf(range) {
  var blob,exportUrl,options,pdfFile,response,sheetTabNameToGet,sheetTabId,ss,ssID,url_base;
  var currentDate = Date()
  range = range ? range : "A1:J85";//Set the default to whatever you want
  sheetTabNameToGet = "VIEW SHEET";//Replace the name with the sheet tab name for your situation
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//This assumes that the Apps Script project is bound to a G-Sheet
  ssID = ss.getId();
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabNameToGet);
  sheetTabId = sh.getSheetId();
  url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  //Logger.log('url_base: ' + url_base)

  exportUrl = url_base + 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +

    '&gid=' + sheetTabId + '&id=' + ssID +
    '&range=' + range + 
    //'&range=NamedRange +
    '&size=Letter' +     // paper size
    '&portrait=true' +   // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' +       // fit to width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true' + //hide optional headers and footers
    '&gridlines=false' + // hide gridlines
    '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    

  //Logger.log('exportUrl: ' + exportUrl)

  options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;//Make sure this is always set

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, options);

  //Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())

  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    console.log("Error exporting Sheet to PDF!  Response Code: " + response.getResponseCode());
    return;

  }
  
  blob = response.getBlob();

  blob.setName('STOCK UPDATE.pdf')

  pdfFile =  DriveApp.getFolderById('10ZXCLT70JzHaURA5I92CAEEfb8J2qBbT')
    .createFile(blob);//Create the PDF file
  //Logger.log('pdfFile ID: ' +pdfFile.getId())
}
```

Comment: How are you triggering the function?  The `range` parameter in `function exportRangeToPDf(range)` is the event object not undefined or null.  So range is not "A1:J85" but the event object.

Comment: You cannot pass a parameter to a function that is triggered with a timebased trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
range = range ? range : "A1:J85"
```

by

```
range = typeof range === 'string' ? range : "A1:J85"
```

The above because when a function is called by a trigger, the trigger pass an event object as parameter, so `range` is not [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) which causes that the url to be fetched to not be built correctly.